# Why haven't more people crossed over from the mirror universe?

Tags: star-trek, mirror-universe

In *Star Trek: Discovery*, Georgiou crosses over from the mirror universe, and from what it seems, she will likely stay in our universe.

The mirror universe is probably not a place you'd want to stay in for very long. In one episode of *Deep Space Nine* Bashir offers mirror O'Brien a chance to cross over for a better life, but he doesn't take it.

With all that in mind, you'd expect a large amount of people attempting to come over trying to escape, but that hasn't been the case. Any canon reason why?

Comment: In one of the continuation novels the Alpha Quadrant is attacked by a swarm of nasties. The Federation dump billions of their people over into the Mirror Universe

Comment: @Valorum - Really!? What novel, probably worth a read.

Comment: Good question. I'll have a rummage and come back to you.

Comment: One does not simply walk into another universe.

Comment: There are undoubtedly many "mirror universes", including some in which the Terran Empire never fell.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A combination of several factors:

- First universal travel is not trivial despite how easy main characters make it seem.
- Second the knowledge of universal travel is most likely classified.
- Third while we may view the mirror universe as a bad place to those that were born there it is home, you mention mirror O’Brien he could have left but he did not because ultimately its where he feels he belongs.